# Android WebView Conservar contenido cuando se cambia de fragmento

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Les consulto si es posible resolver lo siguiente:

- mantener el contenido de un webview contenido en un fragment al cambiar a otro fragment

Lo que tengo implementado y copio abajo, reinicia el contenido cada vez que se muestra el fragment. por ej: si se esta completando un formulario, se vuelve al home (gooogle.com) y se pierde esto.

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

WebView miVisorWeb;

String url = "https://www.google.com/";

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container,false);

    // Bloque 1
    miVisorWeb = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webViewGoogle);
    miVisorWeb.requestFocus();
    WebSettings webSettings = miVisorWeb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        miVisorWeb.loadUrl(url.toString());
         CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        // Bloque 2
        miVisorWeb.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient(){
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });

    miVisorWeb.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return root;
}
}
```

Supongamos que se reproduce un video en el fragment A, cuando cambio al B y retorno al A la idea es que siga viendose la reproducciòn.

Similar a las pestañas de los navegadores, la idea seria esa.

Saludos!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes intentar es lo siguiente:

Recordando un poco el ciclo de vida del fragment, bajo la idea que quieres realizar, puedes mover el código que tienes el método `onCreate()`. Recordemos que este método te permite inicializar algunas cosas y cuando vuelvas a este fragment no volverás a ejecutar esté método **si y solo si** este ya fue creado. Con la idea que tienes como tu fragment ya fue creado, no se volverá a ejecutar (reiniciar). Por ahora lo tienes en el método `onCreateView()` Recomendaría que lo muevas al método `onCreate()`. Luego cuando vas a llamar algún fragment, recuerda que podemos **reemplazar** (método `replace()`) del fragmentManager y podemos `agregar` ( método `add()` ) del fragmentManager. Para tu caso lo que más te conviene es realizar un `add()`. Te dejo un ejemplo:

Para agregar :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

Para reemplazar :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

**Update**

Ejemplo :

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    WebView miVisorWeb;

    String url = "https://www.google.com/";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //inicializar variables, como la url que quieres cargar.
       // Algunas otras cosas que quieres que solo se llame una vez
       url = "https://www.google.com/";
   }

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Aqui inicializar tu vistas y componentes
       View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container,false);

       miVisorWeb = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webViewGoogle);

       return root;
    }


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     //Aqui va todo el código restante
     miVisorWeb.requestFocus();
     WebSettings webSettings = miVisorWeb.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setCacheMode(LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
     webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

     miVisorWeb.loadUrl(url.toString());
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
     // Bloque 2
     miVisorWeb.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient(){
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return false;
       }
     });

      miVisorWeb.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
          @Override
          public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
              if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;
                switch(keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack()){
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                 }
              }

              return false;
           }
       });
    
    } 
}
```

Ahora cuando quieres llamar a otro fragmento lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
// Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

Recuerda que el parámetro `R.id.fragment_container` es el id de tu contenedor de fragments y `firstFragment` es el fragment hacia donde quieres ir. Solo reemplaza esos valores con los que tienes en tu proyecto

Luego, citando tu ejemplo. Si vuelves de B hacia A, el código que tienes en A ya no se ejecutará. Porque solo está en el método `onCreate`

Otra manera de solucionar para que no estes manejando fragments es hacerlo con activities. Siguiendo el mismo ejemplo de fragments. En tu activity, llamémosle A. Agregas todo el código que tienes. Luego simplemente para pasar a a un activity B. llamas a `startActivity`. Cuando haces back tampoco se ejecutara el código que tienes en el método `onCreate` del activity A.

Referencias:
[FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui?hl=es-419#java)

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Hola Gracias! Me podrias subir como queda el metodo oncreate() gracias!!

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta :)